# How to display value from SQL Server database in input box?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, data-binding

I would like to do something like simple data binding in Windows Forms, but in Web Forms. So I would like to get data from a column NAME from table CATS (one row) and display in on website in text box (input type='text') and next I would like to click on "save" button to save this data to database doing an update.

Could you please give me a short snippet of how should I do it to work and get understanding of how does it go?

Comment: I'd recommend going and having a look at some of the tutorials on www.asp.net - this is what they're for.

Comment: Is this winforms or webforms... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really easy updating can come through the detailsview control: https://web.archive.org/web/20211020133929/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/050207-1.aspx